# Задача по Python начальный уровень

Tags: python, for

Условие:

Есть словарь кодов товаров

```
goods = {
    'Лампа': '12345',
    'Стол': '23456',
    'Диван': '34567',
    'Стул': '45678',
}
```

Есть словарь списков количества товаров на складе.

```
store = {
    '12345': [
        {'quantity': 27, 'price': 42},
    ],
    '23456': [
        {'quantity': 22, 'price': 510},
        {'quantity': 32, 'price': 520},
    ],
    '34567': [
        {'quantity': 2, 'price': 1200},
        {'quantity': 1, 'price': 1150},
    ],
    '45678': [
        {'quantity': 50, 'price': 100},
        {'quantity': 12, 'price': 95},
        {'quantity': 43, 'price': 97},
    ],
}
```

Каждая запись отображает сколько и по какой цене закупалось товаров.

Задание: вывести суммарную стоимость каждого ВИДА товара на складе c помощью циклов

```
 Формат вывода:
   <товар_1> - <кол-во_товара_1> шт, стоимость <общая_стоимость_товара_1> руб
   <товар_2> - <кол-во_товара_2> шт, стоимость <общая_стоимость_товара_2> руб
   <товар_4> - <кол-во_товара_3> шт, стоимость <общая_стоимость_товара_3> руб

 Например:
   Стул - 1111 шт, стоимость 8888 руб
   Диван - 2222 шт, стоимость 9999 руб
   и так далее
```

Алгоритм должен получиться приблизительно такой:

```
 цикл for по товарам с получением кода и названия товара
     инициализация переменных для подсчета количества и стоимости товара
     получение списка на складе по коду товара
     цикл for по списку на складе
         подсчет количества товара
         подсчет стоимости товара
     вывод на консоль количества и стоимости товара на складе
```

Часть решения:

```
for title, code in goods.items():
    total_quantity = 0
    total_cost = 0
    for goods in store[code]:
```

Не могу понять как дальше.

Answer (score 6):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# File     : 1093133.py
# Modified : <2020-3-11 Wed 00:57:26 gmt>
# URL      : https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1093133/


from tabulate import tabulate


goods = {
    'Лампа': '12345',
    'Стол': '23456',
    'Диван': '34567',
    'Стул': '45678',
}

store = {
    '12345': [
        {
            'quantity': 27,
            'price': 42,
        },
    ],
    '23456': [
        {
            'quantity': 22,
            'price': 510,
        },
        {
            'quantity': 32,
            'price': 520,
        },
    ],
    '34567': [
        {
            'quantity': 2,
            'price': 1200,
        },
        {
            'quantity': 1,
            'price': 1150,
        },
    ],
    '45678': [
        {
            'quantity': 50,
            'price': 100,
        },
        {
            'quantity': 12,
            'price': 95,
        },
        {
            'quantity': 43,
            'price': 97,
        },
    ],
}


def get_total(list):
    '''Выводит общее количество и суммарную стоимость продукта данной
    категории.'''
    t_qty = 0
    t_prc = 0
    for item in list:
        t_prc+=item['quantity'] * item['price']
        t_qty+=item['quantity']

    return t_qty, t_prc


def main():
    table = []
    for product, code in goods.items():
        quantity, price = get_total(store[code])
        table.append([product, quantity, price])

    print(tabulate(table, headers=['Товар', 'Количество (шт)', 'Oбщая стоимость'], tablefmt='psql'))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()

# End of  1093133.py
```

```
$ ./1093133.py
+---------+-------------------+-------------------+
| Товар   |   Количество (шт) |   Oбщая стоимость |
|---------+-------------------+-------------------|
| Лампа   |                27 |              1134 |
| Стол    |                54 |             27860 |
| Диван   |                 3 |              3550 |
| Стул    |               105 |             10311 |
+---------+-------------------+-------------------+
```

Answer (score 4):

```
for title, code in goods.items():
    total_quantity = 0
    total_cost = 0
    for goods in store[code]:
        total_quantity += goods['quantity']
        total_cost += goods['price']
    print(title, " - ",total_quantity," шт, ",total_cost," руб")
```

Вывод:

```
Лампа  -  27  шт,  42  руб
Стол  -  54  шт,  1030  руб
Диван  -  3  шт,  2350  руб
Стул  -  105  шт,  292  руб
```

Answer (score 1):

Решение со знаниями новичка

```
for product_name, product_code in goods.items():
    item_total_quantity = 0
    item_total_cost = 0
    for product in store[product_code]:
        item_quantity = 0
        item_cost = 0
        item_quantity += product['quantity']
        item_cost += product['price']
        item_total_cost += item_quantity * item_cost
        item_total_quantity += item_quantity
    print('{0} - {1} шт, общая стоимость {2} рублей'.format(product_name, item_total_quantity, item_total_cost))
```

Comment: А почему сразу не присвоить в переменные, например `item_quantity = product['quantity']`?

Answer (score 0):

```
for name_prod, code in goods.items():  # Пробегаемся по словарю "товары" для получением названия товара и его кода
quantity = 0  # инициализация переменной для подсчета количества товара
price = 0  # инициализация переменной для подсчета стоимости товара
cost = 0  # инициализация переменной для подсчета ОБЩЕЙ стоимости товара

for goods in store[code]: # получение списка на складе по коду товара
    quantity += goods['quantity'] # подсчет количества товара
    price = goods['price'] # подсчет стоимости товара
    cost += quantity * price # подсчет ОБЩЕЙ стоимости товара
print(name_prod, " - ", quantity, " шт, ", cost, " руб") # вывод на консоль количества и стоимости товара на складе
```

закомментированы все строки кода поясняющие где что и когда происходит

Comment: Пожалуйста, поясните [прямо в ответе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/1368612/edit), какое преимущество ваше решение имеет по сравнению с ранее данными ответами.